# Converting a string into a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a text document that contains a list of numbers and I want to convert it to a list. Right now I can only get the entire list in the 0th entry of the list, but I want each number to be an element of a list. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this in Python?

```
1000
2000
3000
4000
```

to

```
['1000','2000','3000','4000']
```

Comment: Do you really want `['1000','2000','3000','4000']`? Maybe `[1000,2000,3000,4000]` would be better?

Comment: Your question admits of too many possibilities.  Does the text file only contain a list of numbers, or is that list in a larger context.  Do you get to control how you read from the document or are you stuck with having read a string that contains a bunch of newline or whitespace separated numbers?  Are the numbers in the list always separated by newlines, or are they sometimes separated by other whitespace?  Do you really want a list of strings as your result, or would a list of integers be better?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To convert a Python string into a list use the `str.split` method:

```
>>> '1000 2000 3000 4000'.split()
['1000', '2000', '3000', '4000']
```

`split` has some options: look them up for advanced uses.

You can also read the file into a list with the `readlines()` method of a file object - it returns a list of lines. For example, to get a list of integers from that file, you can do:

```
lst = map(int, open('filename.txt').readlines())
```

---

P.S: See some other methods for doing the same in the comments. Some of those methods are nicer (more Pythonic) than mine

Comment: you're using `str.split`, not `string.split`, the latter is obsolete anyway.

Comment: File objects are iterable, so there is seldom a reason to use the `readlines` method. For example, you could get the same results as your last snippet with `map(int, open('filename.txt'))`.

Comment: List comprehension is usually faster than `map` built-in function plus if the file is big enough iteration over file will be faster and more memory efficient than `readlines`:

`lst = [int(line) for line in open('filename.txt')]`

Comment: `lst = [int(line) for line in open('filename.txt')]` is much better (and more efficient) idiomatic Python for your second example.  *chuckle*  I should read the other comments before I post one.

Comment: This will not close the file. The correct way should be: `with open('filename.txt') as f: lst = map(int, f.readlines())`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> open("myfile.txt").readlines()
>>> lines = open("myfile.txt").readlines()
>>> lines
['1000\n', '2000\n', '3000\n', '4000\n']
>>> clean_lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
>>> clean_lines
['1000', '2000', '3000', '4000']
```

Or, if you have a string already, use `str.split`:

```
>>> myfile
'1000\n2000\n3000\n4000\n'
>>> myfile.splitlines()
['1000', '2000', '3000', '4000', '']
```

You can remove the empty element with a list comprehension (or just a regular `for` loop)

```
>>> [x for x in myfile.splitlines() if x != ""]
['1000', '2000', '3000', '4000']
```

Comment: use `s.splitlines()`, not `s.split("\n")`

Answer (score 1):

```
    $ cat > t.txt
    1
    2
    3
    4
    ^D
    $ python
    Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jul  7 2009, 23:51:51) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> l = [l.strip() for l in open('t.txt')]
    >>> l
    ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    >>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
       data = f.read()
   lines = [s.strip() for s in data.split('\n') if s]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to strip newlines.

```
# list of strings
[number for number in open("file.txt")]

# list of integers
[int(number) for number in open("file.txt")]
```

Comment: And, if the OP were to need to strip newlines, how would that code look?

Comment: You can also just use the `list` builtin instead of a list comprehension - `list(open("myfile.txt"))` -> `['1000\n', '2000\n', '3000\n', '4000\n']`

Comment: @SilentGhost True, it makes it clearer what is happening, but `list(open("myfile"))` is the same as `open("myfile").readlines()` - by default iterating over a file with use the `readlines` method