# How to convert a string into a list in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a string into a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545397/converting-a-string-into-a-list-in-python)

How to convert a string into a list in python such as : `'LIFE IS FULL'` to `['LIFE','IS','FULL']`

Comment: This is a question that takes 2 minutes of google and doc reading.

Comment: So, we have `3` duplicate answers to a duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> strrs="LIFE IS FULL"
>>> strrs.split()
['LIFE', 'IS', 'FULL']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) method:

```
a = "LIFE IS FULL"
b = a.split()
['LIFE','IS','FULL']
```