# How to convert a string to a list at simplest way

Tags: python

If i want to convert the string `'ABCD'` to a list `['A','B','C','D']` what could be the simplest way?

Comment: Are you actually using Python 3?

Comment: You need to show some efforts when asking question. They all might be ridiculously basic, but it's no excuse to not try anything yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a string into a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119431/how-to-convert-a-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

Simplest one I can think of:

```
>> list('ABCD')
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Ref:

- [Python 2 Built-in Functions: list([*iterable*])](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)
- [Python 3 Built-in Types: *class* list([*iterable*])](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case, you may not even have to do that - a string is already iterable:

```
for c in "ABCD"
    print c
```

prints

```
A
B
C
D
```