# How to convert this string into a list in python

Tags: python, list, filter

I have the following code:

```
import re
codes = re.compile(r"\((\d+)\)")
for code in Fixed:
    co_codes = ' '.join(codes.findall(code))
    print(co_codes)
```

which gives me the following string:

```
04344
044
04344
```

I am trying to have all the elements in one list like this:

```
co_codes = [04344, 044, 04344]
```

how can I do that.

Note there are almost 10000 numbers not only three

[notebook code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJt3H.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string into a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545397/converting-a-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Comment: No actually it is like it only sees the first element only and when I try .split() it only gives: ['04344'] and nothing else

Comment: When you check the type it says it is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just generate a list in one shot with list comprehension like this:

```
import re

codes = re.compile(r"\((\d+)\)")
co_codes = [ ''.join(codes.findall(code)) for code in Fixed ]
```

It will give you a list with all strings output

Comment: I did not think of that
Finally it worked
Thanks

Comment: If you need to generate only the list instead of concatenate code in string you needs to use like this:
`co_codes = [ c for c in codes.findall(code) for code in Fixed ]`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `splitlines` method.

```
>>> s = '''04344
... 044
... 04344'''
>>> s.splitlines()
['04344', '044', '04344']
```

Comment: I tried that it only sees the first element which is 04344
even when you try s[1] you get: list index out of range
it only gives: 04344 as an output for s[0]

Comment: @AbdalmalekAburaddaha then your input is different from what you claim it is.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a simple `.split()` would work:

```
a = """04344
044
04344"""
a.split()
```

Comment: no i tried that many times in different ways it did not work.... the below answer did the trick 
Thank you